# web responsive design using tapestry

Tags: html, css, tapestry

I want to build a web responsive website with tapestry, I add the meta data in the head section of the .tml file and used the css for the responsive design. However it doesn't work at all. I tested with an elastic youtube video, which should match the width of the page. I post here the .tml file and the css.

The .tml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
      xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
       <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
       <link href="${context:layout/normalize.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
       <title>${title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- start header -->
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>
                    <t:pagelink page="index">com.example:tutorial1</t:pagelink>
                    &nbsp;
                    version ${appVersion}
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li t:type="loop" source="pageNames" value="pageName" class="prop:classForPageName">
                        <t:pagelink page="prop:pageName">${pageName}</t:pagelink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="video-container">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/R800WcsFj0U" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end header -->
        <!-- start page -->
        <div class="page">
            <!-- start sidebar -->
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <li class="search" style="background: none;">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <t:alerts/>
                    </li>
                    <li t:type="if" test="sidebar">
                        <h2>${sidebarTitle}</h2>

                        <div class="sidebar-content">
                            <t:delegate to="sidebar"/>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- end sidebar -->
            <!-- start content -->
            <div class="content">
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h2>${title}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <t:body/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end content -->
            <br style="clear: both;"/>
        </div>
        <!-- end page -->
        <!-- start footer -->
        <div class="footer">
            <p class="legal">
                &copy;2012 com.example. All Rights Reserved.
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Design by
                <a href="http://www.freecsstemplates.org/">Free CSS Templates</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Icons by
                <a href="http://famfamfam.com/">FAMFAMFAM</a>.
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- end footer -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The css file:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #FFFFFF url(images/img01.jpg) repeat-x;
    text-align: justify;
    font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #626262;
}

form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

input {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #FEFEFE url(images/img13.gif) repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #626262;
    font: normal 1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1, h1 a, h2, h2 a, h3, h3 a {
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Tahoma, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #444444;
}

h1 {
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 2em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

p, ol, ul {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    line-height: 200%;
}

blockquote {
    margin: 0 0 0 1.5em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    border-left: 5px solid #DDDDDD;
}

a {
    color: #1692B8;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Header */

div.header {
    height: 42px;
}

div.logo h1, div.logo p {
    float: left;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

div.logo h1 {
    padding: 0px 0 0 40px;
}

div.logo p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px 0 0 4px;
    line-height: normal;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

div.logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #D0C7A6;
}

div.menu {
    float: right;
}

div.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

div.menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 42px;
}

div.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 20px 0px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #CEC5A4;
}

div.menu .last {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

div.menu a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

div.menu .current_page_item A {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

div.menu .current_page_item a {
}

/* Page */

div.page {
    padding: 40px 40px 0 40px;
}

/* Content */

div.content {
    margin-right: 340px;
}

.post {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.post .title {
    border-bottom: 1px #999999 dashed;
    font-family: Tahoma, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.post .title h2 {
    padding: 30px 30px 0 0px;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2.2em;
}

.post .title p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0px;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #BABABA;
}

.post .title p a {
    color: #BABABA;
}

.post .entry {
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.post .links {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 30px 30px 0px;
}

.post .links a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.post .links a:hover {
}

.post .links .more {
    width: 128px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(images/img03.jpg) no-repeat left center;
}

.post .links .comments {
    width: 152px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(images/img04.jpg) no-repeat left center;
}

/* Sidebar */

div.sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

div.sidebar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

div.sidebar li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: url(images/img10.gif) no-repeat left bottom;
}

div.sidebar li ul {
    padding: 0 30px 40px 30px;
}

div.sidebar li li {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

div.sidebar h2 {
    padding: 30px 30px 5px 10px;
    background: url(images/img09.gif) no-repeat;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #302D26;
}

div.sidebar DIV.sidebar-content {
    width: 265px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

div.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.video-container iframe,  
div.video-container object,  
div.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/* Search */

li.search {
    padding: 20px 30px 40px 30px;
}

li.search input {
    padding: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height: 29px;
    background: #DFDFDF url(images/img14.gif) repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.search #s {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    background: #FEFEFE url(images/img13.gif) repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #626262;
    font: normal 1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

li.search br {
    display: none;
}

/* Categories */

div.sidebar div.categories li {
    background: url(images/img12.gif) no-repeat left center;
}

/* Calendar */

div.calendar_wrap {
    padding: 0 30px 40px 30px;
}

div.calendar table {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

div.calendar thead {
    background: #F1F1F1;
}

div.calendar tbody td {
    border: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}

div.calendar #prev {
    text-align: left;
}

div.calendar #next {
    text-align: right;
}

div.calendar tfoot a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.calendar #today {
    background: #FFF3A7;
    border: 1px solid #EB1400;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #EB1400
}

/* Footer */

div.footer {
    padding: 70px 0 50px 0;
    background: #757575 url(images/img08.gif) repeat-x;
}

div.footer p {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #BABABA;
}

div.footer a {
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #DDDDDD;
}

div.footer a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

div.footer .rss {
    background: url(images/img18.gif) no-repeat left center;
}

div.footer .xhtml {
    background: url(images/img19.gif) no-repeat left center;
}

div.footer .css {
    background/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav { 
        height: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav li {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
        border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-indent: 25px;
    }
}

/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    nav {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        display: none;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav a#pull {
        display: block;
        background-color: #283744;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav a#pull:after {
        content:"";
        background: url('nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        top: 10px;
    }
}

div.footer .legal a {
    padding: 0;
}

/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav { 
        height: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav li {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
        border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-indent: 25px;
    }
}

/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    nav {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        display: none;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav a#pull {
        display: block;
        background-color: #283744;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav a#pull:after {
        content:"";
        background: url('nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        top: 10px;
    }
}

/*Smartphone*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    nav li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your browser, does it show the right path to the css file in the source HTML? You could look in a debugger like FireBug too. Or you could check whether the css file was loaded in the browser.

Comment: The file is loaded. Only the responsiveness isn't working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing brace. It goes between the 2nd and 3rd line below.

```
div.footer .css {
    background/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As Lee Meador already pointed out you are missing the closing braces for your footer declaration, also the background markup is incomplete. it should be something like this (deduced from your other markup):

```
div.footer .css {
   background: url(images/img20.gif) no-repeat left center;
}
@media .... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling your own, I would suggest looking at an existing library that already is responsive, and then customizing it, so save yourself some time instead of re-inventing the wheel.

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) is one such excellent library. You can also integrate it easily into Tapestry using the [tapestry-bootstrap](https://github.com/trsvax/tapestry-bootstrap) integration project. I have used this combo on multiple responsive applications, some exclusively for mobiles, and have been quite successful.